# how do i write a hibernate query with two condition and the result as the union of results of both the coditions

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table in database named Application and its pojo would be

```
    public class Application
{
    private int applicationId;
    private String applicationShort;
    private String applicationName;
    private int userId;
}
```

The applicationId by default would be 0.I am trying to write a query which should return the values for applicationId = 0 by default or the union of results when applicationId= 0 and applicationId = any other applicationId

my hibernate code would be:

```
Session session = getCurrentSession();
        String hql = " From Application a where a.applicationId = :applicationId or  a.applicationId = 0";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("applicationId", applicationId);
        return query.list();
```

But this query will return the result of only one condition check.Is there any better way I could get the required result

Comment: Why do u want the `applicationId` to be zero. Ideally, *any ID in database should starts from `1` not from `0`*. Is there any special reason to set your first `applicationId=0` ? What are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the query as:

```
String hql = " From Application a where a.applicationId in(0,:applicationId)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Placing the small range first & larger one next to it.

```
String hql = "From Application a where a.applicationId = 0 or a.applicationId = :applicationId";
```